# Bind AuthorizeException to custom Exception (or override render method of AuthorizationException)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

We now have render methods for Exceptions since Laravel 5.5 and I wanted to make use of that.
So I wanted to override the AuthorizationException, to just redirect to a default page. Problem is, it does not work.

We have our new custom Exception

```
<?php
namespace App\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;

class CustomAuthorizationException extends AuthorizationException
{
    public function render()
    {
        return redirect(route('dashboard'));
    }
}
```

If I throw a CustomAuthorizationException, all works fine, redirect happens.
Then I tried to bind the normal AuthorizationException to that custom one, but I don't know where.
I tried both

```
$this->app->singleton('\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException', '\App\Exceptions\CustomAuthorizationException');
$this->app->bind('\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException', '\App\Exceptions\CustomAuthorizationException');
```

in AppServiceProvider and bootstrap/app.php respectively.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: just have your exception handler handle that exception, its a framework exception, you aren't the one throwing it or controlling what is thrown there.  these things are not resolved from the container anyway.

Comment: Yeah, we could do that (and we did before 5.5), but we refactored our own Exceptions to 5.5 "standard?" (let's say new functionality) and wanted to keep it consistent. Edit: If it's not possible to extend the default exceptions, then there is no choice, I guess... but there has to be a way :/

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Laravel Gate to do access control, an exception of type 'AuthorizationException' is thrown within trait Illuminate/Auth/Access/HandlesAuthorization. Since it is done in the framework, it is not possible to "override" the 'AuthorizationException' class and expect the framework to throw your custom exception as you want.

However, there is a workaround by hijacking exception handling in app/Exception/Handler.php:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
       if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
           return (new CustomAuthorizationException)->render();
       }
    }
}
```

By adding a conditional handler in the render() function, exceptions of type 'AuthroizationExeption' will be redirected to you custom render() function in which users will be redirected to a custom page.

Comment: I know that, that's what we had in 5.4, so I wanted to restructure it while updating to 5.5. Thanks anyways :)